# Angular HttpClient Post Request to Spring REST API Unknown Error

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc, angular-httpclient

I have a locally running Spring Backend with the following endpoints:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/api/public/projects")
public Iterable<Project> findAllProjectsPublic(){
    return projectRepository.findAll();
}

@GetMapping(path = "/api/private/projects/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Project> findProjectById(@PathVariable Long id){
    return projectRepository.findById(id)
            .map(project -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(project))
            .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
}

@PostMapping(path = "/api/public/projects")
public Project createProject(@RequestBody Project project){
    System.out.println(project);
    return projectRepository.save(project);
}
```

All of the endpoints work as expected, when i test them in Postman.

I implemented a service with following methods in Angular:

```
public getAllProjects(cb) {
    this.http.get<Project[]>(this.API_URL + "/public/projects")
    .subscribe(projects => {
        cb(null, projects);
    }, error => {
        cb(error, null);
    })
}

public getProjectById(id: number, cb){
    this.http.get<Project>(`${this.API_URL}/private/projects/${id}`)
    .subscribe(project => {
        cb(null, project);
    }, error => {
        cb(error, null);
    })
}

public createProject(cb){
    this.http.post(`${this.API_URL}/public/projects`, { name: 'Test'})
    .subscribe(res => {
        cb(null, res);
    }, error => {
        cb(error, null);
    })
}
```

The GET requests do work in Angular aswell, however the POST Request does not work and writes back a 403 Status with error message:

```
Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error
```

When i do change the Post Endpoint in Spring to receive a String instead of my @Request Body like this:

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/api/public/projects")
public Project createProject(String projectname){
    return projectRepository.save(new Project("Test"));
}
```

it works! So it has to be something with the Request Body. But still, i receive a 403 Forbidden Status, which makes absolutely no sense to me.

The Body i sent in Postman is:

```
{
    "name": "Test"
}
```

and that works...

Comment: Make a model of project in angular just like in java pojo class and then set the data to project in service and call it. It will work.

Comment: Sometimes its object can't be accessed using the simple json format in spring.

Comment: Does not work, my Pojo in Java has a AutoGenerated Id and the Name, in Angular the Model does only have the name obviously. Does not work unfortunately

Comment: Aaha that's the problem create a vo object to receive it or string only then set the name to project object.

Comment: But i would like to know why it does not work like this, when it works in Postman.

Comment: See postman direct hit the path with post request where your webapp request first handle by OPTION request. When OPTION request handle well with no issue then actual request take place. Else that unknown error came to play.